# How can you deduct 10 seconds from a running timer in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a quiz and want to deduct 10 seconds from my running timer for every wrong answer selected. Right now, in my setStatusClass function, every time a wrong answer is selected, -10 shows up on my timer (which is what I want) but I am not sure what the next step would be in order to take off 10 seconds from the actual running timer.

```
var timerNumber = document.querySelector("#timer-number")
var instructions = document.querySelector('.instructions')
var questionContainer = document.querySelector('#question-container')

var count = 75;
var myTimer;

var myClock = function () {
    count--
    timerNumber.innerHTML = count;
    if (count === 0) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
}

function clock() {
    instructions.classList.add('hide')
    questionContainer.classList.remove('hide')
    myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
    clearStatusClass(element)
    if (correct) {
        element.classList.add('correct')
    } else {
        element.classList.add('wrong')
        element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            clearInterval(myTimer)
            timerNumber.innerHTML = -10
            myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already declared `count` as a global variable, you can simply access it inside your `setStatusClass` function and do `count = count - 10;`.

Then you can set `timerNumber.innerHTML` to the new value of `count`.

Comment: Thank you Max! That worked. However, for some reason now when I select the wrong answer the first time, it subtracts 10 seconds and then 10 seconds each time I click on anything else. Would that be a problem in my if statement or would I have to dig deeper in the code?

Comment: @dag12—the issue is elsewhere. BTW, you don't have to reset the interval for each wrong answer, just reduce *count*.

Comment: Depends on the value of `element`, which isn't visible in the code provided.

RobG is also correct that the interval doesn't need to be reset if the timer isn't at 0.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help guys. Going to look more into my code to see where I went wrong.